# Update field in another schema with post hook mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have that schemas:

```
var schema = new Schema({
number: {type: Number},
subtotal: {type: Float, required: true},
quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
prodprov: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProdProv'},
order: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('OrderDetail', schema);
```

and

```
var schema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
price: {type: Float, required: true},
idProvider: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Provider'},
idProduct: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
description: {type: String},
quantitySold: {type: Number}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ProdProv', schema);
```

I need to update field "quantitySold" when a post.save happens in order-detail, i've tried this:

```
schema.post('save', function(next){
   //But this point I can't find the prodprov to update field
})
```

How I can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mjim, but that´s code not works. I've modify the code and works! this is my solution:

```
schema.post('save', function(doc){
    var prod = ProdProv.findById(this.prodprov).exec().then((pp) => {
        pp.quantitySold += this.quantity;
        pp.save();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
var ProdProv = require('./ProdProv');

var schema = new Schema({
  number: {type: Number},
  subtotal: {type: Float, required: true},
  quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
  prodprov: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProdProv'},
  order: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order'}
});

schema.post('save', async function(doc){
  var prod = await ProdProv.findById(doc.prodprov);
  prod.quantitySold = doc.quantity;
  prod.save()
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('OrderDetail', schema);
```

Comment: I've edited my solution, this should work with async/await, your solution works fine too.